# Find the polar cone of $K=\{(y_1,..y_m)\in R^{mn}|y_1+...+ y_m\in C\} $

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

Find the polar cone of $K=\{y=(y_1,..y_m)\in R^{mn}|y_1+...+ y_m\in C\} $, where $C$ is a closed convex cone in $R^n$

I have started by using the Theorem of preimage that states:
Assume that $C \in R^m$ is a closed convex cone and A is a $n$ x $m$ matrix. Let $K=\{x\in R^n|Ax \in C\}$. Then $K^o = \{A^T\lambda |\lambda \in C^o\}$

For this problem,  $K^o=\{\lambda= (\lambda_1,...,\lambda_1)\in R^n| \lambda \in C^o\}$.

I am not sure how to finish this problem...mostly rewriting the $\lambda\in C^o$ part.

Comment: Surely $K^0 = \{ (\lambda,...,\lambda) | \lambda \in C^0 \}$?

Comment: @copper.hat could you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449707/finding-the-polar-cone-of-the-given-cone-that-consists-of-vectors-in-mathbbr ? It's also a polar cone problem and I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: @ALannisterL: I took a look and provided a complete answer.